# Fast search of local positive quadruples on the sphere

Tags: computational-geometry

[redirected from math.stackexchange.com]

Let $U = \{u_{1}, u_{2}, \ldots, u_{n}\} \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be the finite set of points on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$: $||u_{i}||_{2} = 1$

**Definition**: Quadruple of points $(u_{i}, u_{j}, u_{k}, u_{l})$ is said to be **positive** if
$$
\exists \alpha_{i j} > 0, \alpha_{i k} > 0, \alpha_{i l} > 0: u_{i} = \alpha_{i j} u_{j} + \alpha_{i k} u_{k} + \alpha_{i l} u_{l}
$$

**Definition**: Positive quadruple $(u_{i}, u_{j}, u_{k}, u_{l})$ is said to be **local** relatively to the set U if $\nexists u_{s} \in U$ such that $(u_{s}, u_{j}, u_{k}, u_{l})$ is positive.

**Question**: Is there any fast algorithm to find all local positive quadruples in the given set $U$?

**EDIT**:
Of course, in worst case the complexity of the algorithm should be $\Theta(n^3)$, since there is an example when there are $\Theta(n^3)$ local positive quadruples.

But suppose that $u_{i}$ are taken from some real-world example, and they are distributed on the sphere somehow uniformly (~close to uniform).

Comment: I take it that $u_s\not = u_i$?

Comment: @TomvanderZanden, yes. $u_s \neq u_i$ in all definitions and all $u_i$ in $U$ are considered to be different.